# Frantions to binary

Tags: binary, discrete-mathematics

Learning how to convert numbers from integers to binary.

I'm working on a fraction of .36 the binary for it is .01011... I understand that to get the binary if a fraction you times the number by 2 and read from the top number down.

So

1. .36 = 0 First number
2. .36 x 2 = .72 =1 , it's still below zero
3. .72 x 2 = 1.44 = 0, as it as it's above zero
4. 1.44 x2 = 2.88 = 1, this is were I get thrown, is it becouse the .88 is closer to 1?
5. 2.88 x2 = 5.76 =1

Giving me the .01011

So is it everything above .5 =1? so

I'm starting to play with floating point numbers so really need to know how to convert binary fractions

Comment: Please don't vandalize your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your method is correct.

Some intuition: to convert an integer to base 2, you repeatedly take mod 2, giving your next digit, then divide by 2. Fractions are similar: think of it as converting to base 1/2: repeatedly take mod 1/2 (1 if the fractional part has 1/2, 0 otherwise), then divide by 1/2.